# Sass ID selector isn't working in React and create-react-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have a library I'm making with a `Header` component and a `Button` component. I gave them ID's to identify them in my SASS file, this is my current situation:

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.module.scss'

export const Button = ({text, bgColor, textColor, fontFamily}) => {

  return <button id="button" style={
    {backgroundColor: [bgColor],
    color: [textColor],
    fontFamily: [fontFamily]}
  }>{text}</button>
}

export const Header = ({text, size, fontFamily, textColor}) => {
  return <h1 style={{
    fontSize: [size],
    fontFamily: [fontFamily],
    color: [textColor]
  }} id="header">{text}</h1>
}

export const subHeader = () => {
  return null
}
```

**styles.module.scss**:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
$font: 'Montserrat',
sans-serif;
$blue: #1778f2;
#button {
    background: $blue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: $font;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: .8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

#header {
    font-family: $font;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

That's isn't working. However, when I replace the ID selectors in my scss file to the element names in HTML (button, h1), it works:

```
button {
    background: $blue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: $font;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: .8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}

h1 {
    font-family: $font;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

What's the problem here? Is it the sass (I'm pretty new to it, BTW I installed node sass so It should work) or something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either rename your `scss` file to remove the `module` from file name:

```
import './styles.scss'
```

or if you want to use `module` pattern in your file name, do this:

```
import styles form './styles.module.scss'
```

And provide *id / class* in this manner:

```
export const Button = ({text, bgColor, textColor, fontFamily}) => {

  return <button id={styles.button} style={ // or className={styles.myClass1}
    {backgroundColor: [bgColor],
    color: [textColor],
    fontFamily: [fontFamily]}
  }>{text}</button>
}

export const Header = ({text, size, fontFamily, textColor}) => {
  return <h1 style={{
    fontSize: [size],
    fontFamily: [fontFamily],
    color: [textColor]
  }} id={styles.header}>{text} // or className={styles.myClass2}
  </h1>
}
```

This behavior is usually implemented by bundlers like webpack, browserify etc. It is not an inherent feature of *sass*.

When you use this module pattern for your sass, the generated stylesheet looks vaguely like this:

```
.moduleName_className__someUniqueId { // for classes
  color: red; 
}

#.moduleName_myId__someUniqueId { // for IDs
  color: blue; 
}
```

**What problem does it solve?**

It provides you unique selectors (IDs and classnames) by adding `moduleName` and *a unique identifier* with them. Which helps you keep your styles organized and separated.

[Docs - add css / scss modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet).

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem. I am using scss files with module pattern.

The simplest solution I could find is using attribute selector.

This does not work:

```
#myID {
   color: red;
}
```

Instead of above code I used below in my module.scss file and worked:

```
h1[id="myID"] {
   color: red;
}
```