# Use bootstrap on one page and not another in reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I am building a reactjs project where in I am using two templates. Now one template uses bootstrap and the other does not. Certain pages of my application are from the first template and others are not.
Now when I put all the CDN's required in my html page(index.html), bootstrap affects the template which does not contain bootstrap.
This also happens if I import bootstrap(bootstrap.min.js) in only the pages I need it in.
Is there a way where bootstrap would be used only in the pages I want and not the others?

Comment: Just don't include the `classNames` where you don't want them to be used.

Comment: You can try using [css or scss module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849714/2873538).