# `.css` or `.scss` does not have effect in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a piece of code in react where in line style works as expected:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ fontSize: 48 }}>LOLOLO</div>
    )
}
```

But if I use `index.css` (where `.me { font-size: 48 }` is defined), the follows has no effect

```
import styles from './index.css'
render() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.me}>LILILILALALA</div>
    )
}
```

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

PS: `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you're using the CRA, then `example.(s)css` is global, whereas `Example.module.s(c)ss` is an importable CSS module. Click [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) for more info.

Comment: I changed the file name to `index.module.css` and `import styles from "./index.module.css"`, it worked. You could post an answer if you like so that I could accept...

Comment: A similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849714/2873538).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
import './index.scss'
render() {
    return (
        <div className="me">LILILILALALA</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about move file extension to `scss`

Comment: It returned `Cannot find name 'me'.  TS2304`.

Comment: Do you use this manual: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/ ?

Comment: I do see `"node-sass": "^4.13.1"` in `package.json`, but I don't know how it is related to my question.

Comment: This help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require?